# software for wiring and designing electric panel

Tags: pcb, wiring, software

I need some help in designing an electric panel. I have designed some pcb's (Power, control, relays...) and I want to place all of them in a nice way (As shown in the pic. The pic is taken from https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KZiqUZGjGc0). I want to know what kind of software you use for the design of the panel and wiring it up.

I apreciate your help.
thanks.[image: panel design]

Comment: Promis-e and Elcad by Aucotec are two (of many).

Comment: I would not call that a panel. I'd call that a box with DIN rail devices mounted in it (and a bunch of exposed wiring/connections.) A panel generally has all the wires hidden behind it (unless there are front-panel inputs, and those are generally to connectors.) The closest thing to a panel in that picture is the bottom of the box, which appears to have a bunch of connectors mounted.

Comment: @Ecnerwal: Those devices are not mounted on the back of the box they are mounted on a panel (or sub-panel). The panel is then mounted to the back of the box. That is called an electrical panel in the industrial control field. An operator's panel or console is made by mounting on the front with wires behind.

Comment: Have a look at [RS DesignSpark](http://www.rs-online.com/designspark/electronics/). It's free. Farnell may have an equivalent.

Answer (score 2):

[Solidworks Eletrical](https://www.solidworks.com/sw/products/electrical-design/solidworks-electrical.htm) would be one piece of software you could use.

[image]
[image]